# check/uncheck radio button by clicking on it using jquery

Tags: jquery

i am trying to unchecking radio buttons by clicking on it  which are dynamically binded in table.i am trying following mentioned code.but it is not getting id.plz provide any solution.below i am providing my code.

```
var a = [];
var strAction;
var loginunit;
var loginUserID;
var length;

$(document).ready(function () {
    //var a = [];
    var databind = "";
    $('#tblcircularmaster').empty()
    var data = Databind("circularmasterapplication");
    data.done(function (result) {
        length = result.ApplicationsResult.length;
        for (i = 0; i < result.ApplicationsResult.length; i++) {
            if (result.ApplicationsResult[i].Application != undefined || result.ApplicationsResult[i].Application != null) {
                a[i] = result.ApplicationsResult[i].Application;

            }
        }
        var k = 0, b;
        for (j = 0; j < Math.ceil(a.length / 3) ; j++) {

            b += '<tr><td><input " onclick="chose();" type="radio" value="' + a[k] + '" id="' + a[k] + '">' + a[k] + ' </td><td><input onclick="chose();" type="radio"   value="' + a[k + 3] + '" id="' + a[k + 3] + '">' + a[k + 3] + '</td><td><input onclicke="chose();"   value=' + a[k + 6] + ' type="radio"   id="' + a[k + 6] + '">' + a[k + 6] + '</td></tr>';
            k = k + 1;

        }

        $("#tblcircularmaster").append(b);
    })
})

function chose(id) {
 if (document.getElementById(id).checked == true) {
            (document.getElementById(id).checked == false)
        }
        else  {
            (document.getElementById(id).checked == true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: pass id in onclick="chose();" like this onclick="chose(id);"

Comment: onclick="chose(this.id)"